# Possible upgrades for Lenovo Yoga 700 touchpad driver?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, touchpad, lenovo

I was having a conversation with a coworker about how I've been trying out  Ubuntu on a Lenovo Yoga 700 I picked up for cheap. I'm primarily a Mac user, so it's been rather difficult for me to get used to the trackpad. He recommended I look into upgrading my driver to see if I could find an experience more akin to a Mac. I've done a bit of research to figure out how I would even go about doing that, but have been coming up short. Does anyone know if that is a possibility?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

If this his helpful, when I run `xinput list` I see:

```
↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

and when I run `xinput list-props 13` I see:

```
Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (147):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (149): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (286): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (287): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (288):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (289):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (290):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (291):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (292):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (293):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (294):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (295):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (296):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (297):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (298):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (299):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (300):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (301): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (302):    0, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (303):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (304):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (305):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (306): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (307): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (308): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (309): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (267): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (268):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (269):    0, 0
    Device Node (270):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (271):    2, 14
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (310):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (311):   1
```